# Raspberry Pi to Digital LEDs, No Soldering

Tags: led, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi laying around right now that I'd like to put to use, and I'm also going to be buying a string of digital LED pixels from Adafruit (the string of 25 WS2801 pixels).

I know I can easily control the pixels from the Arduino based on the Adafruit tutorial, but I'd prefer not to buy a new Arduino if I can do this from the Pi.

Based on several projects I've seen, such as [PixelPi](https://github.com/PixelPi/PixelPi), it's obviously possible, but because I have no space for a soldering iron (I live in a dorm hall, and stuff like that is not allowed for obvious reasons), so I can't do any soldering. I would *like* to be able to learn how to solder and simply go to a hacker space, but I don't see having that much time any time in the near future...

Is there a way to connect the RGB pixels to the Raspberry Pi without any soldering? The only way I could think of doing that would be to use some sort of adapter for the header pins so I can push the wires into them (without having to solder), but I'm not experienced enough with electronics to know exactly what to look for...

Alternatively, if no one knows a way, I guess I might as well just spend the extra $20 and get an Arduino...

Comment: Ah, this is what I was referring to: https://www.adafruit.com/products/826. Would this work to connect the Raspberry Pi to the LED pixels?

Comment: The headers on the Raspberry Pi are male headers, so you'll need a female connector. This is what you want: https://www.adafruit.com/products/914 or https://www.adafruit.com/products/1105. You will have to assemble either kit though. If your school has an EE program maybe you can visit one of their classrooms to use their equipment.

Comment: * with permission, of course

Comment: @SimpleCoder - Hell with that, break in, and if your project turns out awesome enough, I bet they'll be ok with it.

Comment: @SimpleCoder The afterthought *with permission, of course* made me laugh.

Comment: Good grief, the amount of soldering I did in a college dorm. It's a wonder I wasn't thrown in jail! or maybe things have changed in *cough* years. +1 for asking permission though - not-to-busy lab techs can be a great source of practical help...

Comment: Are the Pi and the pixels the same voltage? I thought the Pi header was 3.3V and the pixels are 5V - worth checking.

Comment: Based on the diagram here (http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals), it looks like there's both 3.3V and 5V header pins, which corresponds to the diagram used in the Adafruit tutorial I am basing my "knowledge" (http://learn.adafruit.com/light-painting-with-raspberry-pi/hardware) on :P I may just end up using a breakout board, though with the header extenders I posted above (female for connecting to the Pi, male to insert into the breadboard), it that works...

Comment: @AnindoGhosh: It sounded perfectly innocent when I first clicked "Add Comment". :)

Comment: The RPi I/O is 3V3. The 5V is mostly for supplying the USB ports with power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using a soldering iron, you can connect a Pi to some LEDs and resistors etc using

- a Raspberry Pi
- some male to female jumper cables ([example](http://www.makershed.com/Male_to_Female_Jumper_Wires_p/mkkn5.htm))
- a small breadboard ([example](http://www.makershed.com/product_p/mkkn2.htm))

[image: pi breadboard]
<sup>*(photo from [RPi SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/3932/2955))*</sup>

Comment: I actually solve the problem a while ago with electrical tape and jumper cables-to-wire (since I didn't want to use a breadboard), as seen here: http://www.andrewmunsell.com/blog/raspberry-pi-leds/. Since then, I've gone ahead and cleaned everything up by using heatshrink and hot glue to keep everything in place, and I actually do have access to a soldering iron now so I could potentially finish it off properly. I'm going to mark this answer as correct because it's the best (proper) way to do it w/o a soldering iron.

Comment: Don't get a small breadboard though. Get a big breadboard (or at least a medium sized one) and you'll be glad you have the space. (Don't get the stupidly expensive big ones either)